# Align items and text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, itemize

I just started using TikZ and i have some problems aligning the items.
I want to add sort of description of my boxes. My plan is to add the descriptions with `\node` and connect it with `\draw` lines. My problem now is, that text and items are aligned right. How do I align it left?
example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,angles,calc,positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows.meta,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum size = 1cm,text width=8mm,align=center ,draw=black!50}]
        \matrix(mtx-bez) [row sep=1cm, column sep=0cm, very thick]{
        \node (mat) [box] {C\\};
        &\node (besch) [box] {17\\};
        &\node (beton) [box] {a\\};
        &\node (knt) [box] {0\\};
        \\};

        \matrix(mtx-tex) [right=5mm of mtx-bez, row sep=1cm, column sep=0cm, very thick]{
        \node  (tex) [box] {3200\\};
        \\};

        \matrix(mtx-einbl) [right=5mm of mtx-tex, row sep=1cm, column sep=0cm, very thick]{
        \node  (einbl) [box] {X3\\};
        \\};

        \matrix(mtx-nr) [right=5mm of mtx-einbl, row sep=1cm, column sep=0cm, very thick]{
        \node  (vers) [box] {V\\};
        & \node  (nr) [box]{01\\};
        \\};

        %\node (probennr) [align=center] at (9,-2){Probennummer 01-05};

        \node  [below right =2cm and 0.5cm of vers.south, anchor=west, align=left] (versart) {Versuchsart:};
        \node [below=7.5mm of versart,anchor=west, align=left, text width=4cm ] (versopt) {
            \begin{itemize}         
                    \item [\textbf{V}...Verbundversuch]
                    \item [\textbf{Z}...Zugversuch]
                    \item [\textbf{T}...Querzug]
            \end{itemize}
        };

        \begin{scope}[shorten >= 2mm, shorten <=2mm]
            \draw (knt.east) -- (tex.west);
            \draw (tex.east) -- (einbl.west);
            \draw (einbl.east) -- (vers.west);
            %\draw [dotted] (nr.south) |- (probennr);
            \draw [dotted] (vers) |- (versart.west);
        \end{scope}


    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Versuchskörperbezeichnung}
    \label{fig:bezeichnung}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were inserting the texts inside the `\itemize`'s `[]` environment. If you remove it and change your anchor to `east` (optional),

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,angles,calc,positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows.meta,arrows}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum size = 1cm,text width=8mm,align=center ,draw=black!50}]
            \matrix(mtx-bez) [row sep=1cm, column sep=0cm, very thick]{
            \node (mat) [box] {C\\};
            &\node (besch) [box] {17\\};
            &\node (beton) [box] {a\\};
            &\node (knt) [box] {0\\};
            \\};

            \matrix(mtx-tex) [right=5mm of mtx-bez, row sep=1cm, column sep=0cm, very thick]{
            \node  (tex) [box] {3200\\};
            \\};

            \matrix(mtx-einbl) [right=5mm of mtx-tex, row sep=1cm, column sep=0cm, very thick]{
            \node  (einbl) [box] {X3\\};
            \\};

            \matrix(mtx-nr) [right=5mm of mtx-einbl, row sep=1cm, column sep=0cm, very thick]{
            \node  (vers) [box] {V\\};
            & \node  (nr) [box]{01\\};
            \\};

            %\node (probennr) [align=center] at (9,-2){Probennummer 01-05};

            \node  [below right =2cm and 0.5cm of vers.south, anchor=west, align=left] (versart) {Versuchsart:};
            \node [below=7.5mm of versart,anchor=center,  align=left, text width=4cm ] (versopt) {
                \begin{enumerate}           
                        \item[] \textbf{V}...Verbundversuch
                        \item[] \textbf{Z}...Zugversuch
                        \item[] \textbf{T}...Querzug
                \end{enumerate}
            };

            \begin{scope}[shorten >= 2mm, shorten <=2mm]
                \draw (knt.east) -- (tex.west);
                \draw (tex.east) -- (einbl.west);
                \draw (einbl.east) -- (vers.west);
                %\draw [dotted] (nr.south) |- (probennr);
                \draw [dotted] (vers) |- (versart.west);
            \end{scope}


        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Versuchskörperbezeichnung}
        \label{fig:bezeichnung}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

you will get:

[image]

you can now play with positioning it at your desired location `;)`.